# Show JSON data from Request Body POST

Tags: php, json

I found the following test code (sendJSON.php):

```
<?php
$article = new stdClass();
$article->UserName = "JohnDoe";
$article->userPassword = "MyPassword";

$json_data = json_encode($article);

$post = file_get_contents('readJSON.php',null,stream_context_create(array(
'http' => array(
    'protocol_version' => 1.1,
    'user_agent'       => 'PHPExample',
    'method'           => 'POST',
    'header'           => "Content-type: application/json\r\n".
                          "Connection: close\r\n" .
                          "Content-length: " . strlen($json_data) . "\r\n",
    'content'          => $json_data,
),
)));

if ($post) {
    echo $post;
} else {
    echo "POST failed";
}
?>
```

trying to get the $json_data from the Request Body in the server side readJSON.php. here is my simple readJSON.php file:

```
<?php
  echo file_get_content("PHP://input");
?>
```

Problem is server side page is not echo-ed?

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Try `echo file_get_contents("php://input");`.

Comment: @Gordon - I understand the need to prevent duplicate post, but try to help answer a question and not be to quick to edit it... I'm not asking how to handle POSTed data but header data...

Comment: @BarclayVision — But the JSON isn't in the header

Comment: I guess that's part of my question? Since I can't just read the POST data - where is it located when it is sent to the server and how can it be retrieved?

Comment: @BarclayVision You are POST'ing raw Json in the Request body (not header). The linked question already has answers to that (Niet's comment also answers it). If those answers do not fully address your question, either ask a new one or edit your question to point out why they do not solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you all for the clarification - I didn't understand how the Request Body was sent - very helpful from all of you. @niet if you will post as answer I'll mark.

Comment: Still have problem seeing Request Body : changed my question and code...